# Do I need the verb "be" with the adverb + "ing forms"?

Tags: verbs

I came across this sentence:

> My sense suddenly tingling warning me of danger!

And I would like to understand what it is:

> *My sense suddenly tingling*

Is this a noun phrase? It's just that I would write this sentence with **be**:

> My sense *are* suddenly tingling

Did they just omit the verb *be*, or is it a noun phrase (or gerund)?

Comment: "My sense suddenly tingling warning me of danger!" is grammatically incorrect, especially without context. for example "I turned the corner. My sense suddenly tingling warning me of danger, i ducked" could be considered correct, if a little weird

Comment: @flumperious it's a comic book and there's just a new frame with the character's thought(which is written above) . The previous sentence was something like: " I'll shoot my roll and bounce off to the police station  "

Comment: if its a thought bubble, then you are correct, "My sense is suddenly tingling warning me of danger!" would be grammatically correct (if the character has some kind of superpower-sense)

Comment: @Man_From_India if something is tingling, then it doesn't necessarily need a preposition (see the examples at the bottom: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tingling )

Comment: @flumperious yes I had already realised it and deleted my comment, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Idiomatically, it's almost always ***plural*** when we talk about [***our senses tingling***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+senses+tingled%2Cmy+sense+tingled%2Chis+senses+tingled%2Chis+sense+tingled&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20senses%20tingled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20senses%20tingled%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmy%20senses%20tingled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20senses%20tingled%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The first example text ***My sense suddenly tingling warning me of danger*** isn't a "sentence"  (because it doesn't include an "active" verb) - it's just a fairly lengthy ***noun phrase***. The least change to make it "valid" would be *My senses suddenly tingling **warned** me of danger*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you very much , that's exactly what I wanted to confirm. yes you are right, misspelled with is

Comment: ...another equally small change to make a valid sentence would be *My senses suddenly **tingled**, warning me of danger* (using "to tingle" rather than "to warn" as the "active" verb). Note that *this* version requires a pause after the active verb ***tingled*** (i.e. - it requires a ***comma*** there in the written version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way the person wrote it is more in a book or poetry context so that would be fine, but to speak you would say “my senses are suddenly tingling, warning me of danger”

Answer (score -1):

This sentence lacks something and that I think is the main verb..
"Warning" is the gerund I presume

It should have been stated like this:

> My sense suddenly **started** tingling, warning me of danger

So by this idea, if we ignore the main verb then it is OK and grammatically correct
which I have seen it is  said in *slang* form of conversations

**AND OF COURSE**

The present continues tense is grammatically correct as well, and we all now that present continues or progressive can be used in situations that are just started to take place

> My sense ***is*** suddenly tingling, warning me of danger

Comment: Auxiliary "be" verb can also be used instead of "started". Another scenario, "My senses suddenly tingling was warning me of danger".

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes that is correct it refers to the past tense of a sentence